# Nilpotent matrices condition with traces

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

One [property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) of nilpotent matrices is that a matrix $N$ is nilpotent if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(N^k)=0$ for all $k>0$. How can this property be proved?

Comment: look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/trace-of-powers-of-a-nilpotent-matrix

Comment: What can you say about the eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix, using the definition of eigenvalue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ the eigenvalues of $N$ repeated with their multiplicities and notice that if $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $N^k$ so since $\operatorname{tr}(N^k)=0$ we find the system of equations
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^k=0\quad k=1,\ldots,n$$

Now we solve this system by induction:

- the case $n=1$ is immediate
- assume we have the result for $n-1$
- Let
  $$P(x)=(x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_n)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$
  so 
  $$0=\sum_{i=1}^nP(\lambda_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^n+a_{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^{n-1}+\cdots+na_0=na_0$$
  hence $a_0=0$ and then $0$ is eigenvalue of $N$ and WLOG assume $\lambda_n=0$ and finaly the induction's hypothesis gives $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_{n-1}=0$. What we can say about a matrix which all its eigenvalues $0$?

Comment: Thanks, Sami. From the same link, I see the fact that a matrix which all its eigenvalues $0$ must be nilpotent. But after some thought I still can't see why. Could you please explain there?

Comment: What's the characteristic polynomial of $N$?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $x^n$. How to relate it to nilpotency?

Comment: Do you know Cayely-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: Okay. I learned it a long time ago and forgot about it. Anyway, that solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

This follows from Engel's theorem: a nilpotent Matrix can ( by a suitable Base change) be brought in strictly triangular form (with 0's on the diagonal) from which the claim is immediate.