# if A is nil-potent prove for some B, AB-BA=A

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $A \in M_n(C) $. prove $A$ is nil-potent iff for some matrix $B$ we have 
$AB-BA=A$.

i found this question in a math competition and i can prove the opposite side of this question but i have no idea for another side.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you construct a $B$ pretty easily if you assume $A$ is made up of blocks like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ & 0 & 1 \\ &&\ddots&\ddots \\ &&&\ddots &1 \\ & & & & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: A proof of one of the implications is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724294/if-a-ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent).

Comment: $P^{-1}APP^{-1}BP-P^{-1}BPP^{-1}AP= P^{-1}AP^{-1}$  by using this idea from your comment and by $L(X)=AX-XA$ that is a linear transformation and calculating $L(e_{ij})=A_i - A'_j$ and using this fact in i'th column and row we have atmost one $1$. i think it's pretty trivial.$A_i and A'_j is i'th column and j'th row. am i right Ted Shifrin?

Comment: by the way thank you for help,Ted Shifrin.