# Complex matrixes $A$, $B$ such that $AB - BA = B$. Prove that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There are complex matrices $A$, $B$ such that $AB - BA = B$. Prove that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $B$.

I know that $tr(B)=0$. I tried different transformations and I ran out of ideas. Can you please help me?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724294/if-a-ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent?noredirect=1&lq=1) (we can rename $A$ by $-B$ and $B$ by $A$ to obtain $AB-BA=B$).

Comment: @Dietrich-Burde, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $ \mathrm{sp}\left(B\right)\neq\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace\cdot $ Since $ B\neq O_{n} $, then $ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ B^{k}\neq O_{n} \cdot $ (Or else $ B $ would be nilpotent and would have $ 0 $ as the only eigenvalue)

Define, an endomorphism $ \varphi_{A}:\mathscr{M}_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)\rightarrow\mathscr{M}_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right),\ X\mapsto AX-XA $, then we have, for any $ k\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, the following : \begin{aligned}\varphi_{A}\left(B^{k}\right)=AB^{k}-B^{k}A=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(B^{i}A B^{k-i}-B^{i+1}AB^{k-1-i}\right)}&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{B^{i}\left(AB-BA\right)B^{k-1-i}}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{B^{i}BB^{k-1-i}}\\ \varphi_{A}\left(B^{k}\right) &=kB^{k}\end{aligned}

Thus $ \left\lbrace 1,2,3,\cdots\right\rbrace\subset\mathrm{sp}\left(\varphi_{A}\right) $, which is impossible since $ \dim\left(\mathscr{M}_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)\right)<+\infty $, and $ \left|\left\lbrace 1,2,3,\cdots\right\rbrace\right|=+\infty \cdot $

Thus, $$ \mathrm{sp}\left(B\right)=\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace $$

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend that $B^{-1}$ exists.
So we can have

$$A B B^{-1}-B A B^{-1}=B B^{-1}$$

$$A - B A B^{-1}= I$$

$$tr(A - B A B^{-1})= tr(I)$$

$$tr(A) - tr(B A B^{-1})= tr(I)$$
And $ tr(B A B^{-1}) = tr( A B^{-1} B) = tr(A)$

$$tr(A) - tr(A)= tr(I)$$

$$ 0 \neq tr(I) = n$$

It means that $B^{-1}$ cannot exist --> $B$ is a singular matrix($det(B)=0$) --> one eigenvalue is $0$

Comment: Singular matrices need not have every eigenvalue zero.

Comment: year, I'm sorry. Only one eigenvalue must be $0$. Now you now that $det(B) = 0$

Comment: You have not shown that there cannot be any other eigenvalue. It can be done by contradiction

Comment: You can use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix  But I don't now how