# Jacobson Lemma from Herstein

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This question is asked in chapter-6.8 of **Topics in Algebra** by **I N Herstein** -

Prove the Jacobson lemma for elements $A,B\in F_{n}$ **if $n$ is less than the characteristic of $F$.**

$F_{n}$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices.

**Jacobson lemma**- https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82031256.pdf

In lemma, characteristic of $F$ is $0$. So I am confused how to prove this question. What is the meaning of $n$ is less than the characteristic of $F$?

I know the proof when characteristic of $F$ is $0$. It is given in the book.

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: [The usual proof using derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/228033) should work without modification because $n!\ne0$ when $n<\operatorname{char}(F)$.

Comment: I understand your point. But, if I use this lemma: "If characteristic of $F$ is 0 and tr$A^{i}=0$ for $i≥1$ then $A$ is nilpotent" then what is the meaning of $n$ is less than characteristic of $F$?

Comment: @TanyaRastogi No, it doesn't mean that, but the statement is still true when $n<\operatorname{char}(F)$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/711898) for instance. The conventional proof that uses Newton's identities also work, (again) because $n!\ne0$.