# If $A $ is a square matrix of size $n$ with complex entries such that $Tr(A^k)=0 , \forall k \ge 1$ , then is it true that $A$ is nilpotent ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

If $A$ is a  square matrix of size $n$  with complex entries and is nilpotent , then I can show that all the eigenvalues of $A^k$ , for any $k$ , is $0$ , so $Tr(A^k)=0 , \forall k \ge 1$ . Now conversely if $A $ is a square matrix of size $n$ with complex entries such that $Tr(A^k)=0 , \forall k \ge 1$ , then is it true that $A$ is nilpotent ?

Comment: For a field of characteristic $p>0$ it is not true, i.e., for $A=I_p$ the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true. Let $\lambda_i, i=1,\ldots, n$ denote the eigenvalues of your matrix. Then $\sum \lambda_i^k=0, k\in \mathbb{N}^*.$ This implies that $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$. 
Just found that it is a duplicate: [Traces of all positive powers of a matrix are zero implies it is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/trace-of-powers-of-a-nilpotent-matrix)