# Prove matrix $A$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix and we have 
>   $$\mathrm{tr}(A)=\mathrm{tr}(A^2)=\mathrm{tr}(A^3)=\cdots=\mathrm{tr}(A^n)=0.$$
>   Prove that $A$ is a nilpotent matrix.

We know $\mathrm{tr}(A)=\sum_i \lambda_i$, and $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your condition only holds in characteristic zero. If the characteristic is $2$, for instance, the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix satisfies the conditions.

And then, note that if $\lambda_{i}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, for $i = 1, \dots, n$, then the eigenvalues of $A^{k}$ are the $\lambda_{i}^{k}$, so that the trace of $A^{k}$ is $\sum \lambda_{i}^{k}$. Now use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities):
$$
ke_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1} e_{k - i} (x_1, \ldots, x_n) p_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n),
$$
where $e_{k}$ is the $k$-th elementary symmetric function, and $p_{k}$ is the sum of the $k$-th powers.

These show that the elementary symmetric functions in the eigenvalues are zero. These are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is then...

Comment: The $2\times2$ identity matrix does not work as a counterexample as the trace is $1+1=2$.

Comment: @Element118 I wrote very very clearly that for that example I was assuming that the characteristic is $2$, so that $1 + 1 = 0$. Of course I make mistakes, like anybody else, but I found bemusing that you deem me uncapable to compute $1 + 1$.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the phrasing "characteristic zero", but I saw you typed "satisfies the conditions", which I assumed were the conditions $\text{trac}(A^i)=0$.

Comment: @Element118, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: $A_{n×n}$ is nilpotent if and only if all its eigenvalues are $0$.

Proof: Suppose $A$ has all eigenvalues equal to $0$. Then the characteristic
polynomial of $A$ is $χ(x) = (x−\lambda_1)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(x−\lambda_n) = x^n$ so, by the Cayley-Hamilton
Theorem, $\chi(A) = A^n = 0$, making $A$ nilpotent. The converse direction is obvious.

Now [JBC](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33615/jbc)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/159201) to the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/traces-of-all-positive-powers-of-a-matrix-are-zero-implies-it-is-nilpotent) completes the proof:

> Suppose $A$ is not nilpotent, so $A$ has some non-zero eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r$.
>   Let $n_i$ the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ then $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}n_1\lambda_1+\cdots+n_r\lambda_r&=&0 \\ \vdots &  & \vdots \\ n_1\lambda_1^r+\cdots+n_r\lambda_r^r&=&0\end{array}\right.$$
>   So we have $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\cdots&\lambda_r\\\lambda_1^2 & \lambda_2^2 & \cdots & \lambda_r^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \lambda_1^r & \lambda_2^r & \cdots & \lambda_r^r\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}n_1 \\ n_2 \\ \vdots \\ n_r \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 0\end{array}\right)$$
>   But $$\mathrm{det}\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\cdots&\lambda_r\\\lambda_1^2 & \lambda_2^2 & \cdots & \lambda_r^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \lambda_1^r & \lambda_2^r & \cdots & \lambda_r^r\end{array}\right)=\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_r\,\mathrm{det}\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ \lambda_1&\lambda_2&\cdots&\lambda_r\\\lambda_1^2 & \lambda_2^2 & \cdots & \lambda_r^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \lambda_1^{r-1} & \lambda_2^{r-1} & \cdots & \lambda_r^{r-1}\end{array}\right)\neq 0$$
>   (Vandermonde)
>
> So the system has a unique solution which is $n_1=\ldots=n_r=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: When you quote a source, you need to make clear what you quote, and provide proper attribution. You linked to the question and said that you took it from another answer, so there's no suspicion of plagiarism, but you should link directly to the answer you're quoting in such cases, not only to the question.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel for your precious advice.