# A problem about commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian matrices of the same size. If $AB − BA$
and $A − B$ commute, show that $A$ and $B$ commute.

I'm not sure where to start with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $A-B$ commute would't: $A-B=B-A \Rightarrow A-B+A=B \Rightarrow 2A-B=B \Rightarrow  2A=2B \Rightarrow A=B$ ?  In witch case $AB = AA = BB $ that obviously commute, is there an error in the question ?

Comment: It seems to me that the question is really trying to say: Let $M_1 = AB-BA$ and let $M_2 = A-B$. Then show $M_1M_2 = M_2M_1$.

Comment: @ Zach Boyd , Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ZachBoyd. Isn't it rather: show that if $M_1 M_2 = M_2 M_1$ then $AB = BA$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C=AB-BA.$ Then for $m\geq 1$

$$C^m=C^{m-1}(AB-BA)=C^{m-1}A(B-A)+C^{m-1}(A-B)A.$$
Thus 
\begin{align*}
\text{trace}  (C^m)=&  \text{trace} (C^{m-1}A(B-A))+  \text{trace} (C^{m-1}(A-B)A) \\=&-\text{trace}(A-B)C^{m-1}A +  \text{trace} (C^{m-1}(A-B)A)\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (\text{as trace}(ST)=\text{trace (TS)})\\
=& - \text{trace} (C^{m-1}(A-B)A)+ \text{trace} (C^{m-1}(A-B)A)\\&
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\text{as}~ C(A-B)=(A-B)C))\\&=0.
\end{align*}
Since $\text{trace}  (C^m)=0$ for all $m,$ $~C$ is nilpotent.(The link of the proof of this is given in the comment)

Also $C^*=(AB-BA)^*=(AB)^*-(BA)^*=B^*A^*-A^*B^*=BA-AB=-C.$

Thus $(iC)^*=\bar i C^*=-i(-C)=iC.$

Thus $iC$ is a Hermitian nilpotent matrix. Hence it must be $0,$ that is $C=0.$

Hence $AB=BA.$

Comment: This is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/traces-of-all-positive-powers-of-a-matrix-are-zero-implies-it-is-nilpotent