# $r\in A$ is in the Jacobson radical iff $\operatorname{tr}(rs)=0\forall s\in A$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra for a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Thus, I can regard any element $r\in A$ as a linear function $(r\cdot{})\colon A\to A$ of finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces. I have come across the following statement.

**Dickson's criterion:** An element $r\in A$ is contained in the Jacobson radical $J(A)$ if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(rs)=0$ for all $s\in A$.

However, I have failed to find a proof, either by myself or by looking on the internet. I am even not sure if the statement is correct this way. Any precisition, proof and/or reference  is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting: I haven't seen this before now.

I think you want to make use of this fact that

> For a field of zero characteristic, if the powers of a matrix all have trace zero, then the matrix is nilpotent.

I would have liked to provide a concrete reference for this, but I haven't found one. All sorts of references prove this for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, but I'm fairly sure it holds for fields of characteristic $0$ in general.  I'm pretty sure the approach given at [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/159170/29335) indicates that it is so.

So in your case, given $s\in A$, $0=\mathrm{tr}(rs)=\mathrm{tr}(rsrs)=\cdots$ so that $rs$ is nilpotent. This means $rA$ is a nil right ideal, and the Jacobson radical contains all nil right ideals.

Conversely, since the Jacobson radical of an Artinian ring is a nilpotent ideal, anything of the form $rs$ with $r\in J(A)$ and $s\in A$ will be nilpotent as well, and as is well known nilpotent transformations have trace $0$.

Comment: See Corollary 4.1 **(b)** in [my note *The trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf) for your fact, stated for arbitrary commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras (but keep in mind that you need the field to have characteristic $0$, or at least not dividing $n!$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix).

Comment: Also note that you have only proven one direction of the criterion.

Comment: I am wondering to what extent this all can be generalized beyond fields. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring in which $1, 2, \ldots, n$ are invertible, and let $A$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra that is a finite free $\mathbb{K}$-module. Is it true that $J\left(A\right) = \left\{a \in A \mid \operatorname{Tr}\left(as\right) \in J\left(\mathbb{K}\right) \text{ for all } s \in A\right\}$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I went ahead and put in a note about the trivial direction. Thanks.  And thanks for the citation!

Comment: And wait.. what? I put "positive characteristic"?  That's the *opposite* of what I intended.

Comment: As $tr(ab)=tr(ba)$ I wonder if looking at $A/I\cong k[x]/(f(x))$ with $I$ the two-sided ideal generated by the $ab-ba$ can help

Comment: The question asked in my third comment here now [has its own MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332518/relative-dickson-trace-criterion-for-jacobson-radical).