# Trace Criterion

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ with $char(F) = 0$  and $ T: V \rightarrow V $ a linear map. Suppose that $Tr(T^n)=0$ for all $n≥1.$  Show that $T$ nilpotent.

I have seen a proof that uses the Fitting's lemma. I believe there should be some straight-forward proof from scratch. Could you help me with some suggestions? Thanks so much.

Comment: See [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167) for instance. The question assumes that the field is complex, but two of the answers work over any field of characteristic $0$ or characteristic $>n$.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, it does. I have already looked at this post. This answer is cute. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, there exists some coefficients $a_1$, ..., $a_n$ such that
$$a_n T^n + a_{n-1}T^{n-1} + ... + a_1 T + \mathrm{det}(T) \mathrm{Id}=0$$

Taking the trace, you get $\mathrm{det}(T)=0$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue. Now you can make an induction over the dimension.

**Edit :** Antoher way to prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue would be to rewrite the condition on the traces with a Vandermonde system.

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: @ TheSilverDoe, Thank you very much