# $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=0 \space \forall k\in \Bbb{Z}^+$ implies $A$ is nilpotent. Does this imply $\operatorname {char}(K) =0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question, trace

$\mathcal{M}_{n}(K) $: Set of all $n×n$  matrices over the field $K$.

$A\in \mathcal{M}_{n}(K) $ is called nilpotent if $A^k=\textbf{0}$ for some $k\in \Bbb{Z}^+$

---

It is clear that if $A$ is nilpotent then $\operatorname{tr}(A^k) =0$ for all $k\in \Bbb{Z}^+$

---

The converse is also true if $\operatorname{char}(K) =0$

---

My question: Suppose for a matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(K)$, $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=0 \space  \forall k\in \Bbb{Z}^+ $ implies $A$ is nilpotent.
Can we conclude that $\operatorname{char}(K) =0$?

Comment: Have you considered the identity matrix?

Comment: I'm sorry but what's $char(K)$ again ?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#:~:text=As%20mentioned%20above%2C%20the%20characteristic,positive%20characteristic%20or%20prime%20characteristic.&text=of%20prime%20order.,and%20this%20isomorphism%20is%20unique.           
                   Characteristic of the field $K$ which is either $0$ or prime.

Comment: No. Take $n=1$. You have that $A$ is a scalar, and the trace is the identity. 

Then the property that $A^k=0\implies A=0$ is true for every field.

Comment: If you mean that it must hold also for every $n$, then yes, since the identity matrix of size $p$ (being the char of the field) has trace zero with all its powers

Comment: in general you can only apply the converse for (i) characteristic zero and (ii) when $n\lt p$ for prime $p$

Comment: Are we assuming the condition is true for *one specific $n$* or simultaneously *for all $n$*?

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement "If $A \in M_n(K)$ is such that for all $k \ge 1$, $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=0$, then $A$ is nilpotent."

Claim: $P(n) \Leftrightarrow (\operatorname{char}(K) = 0 \text{ or } n < \operatorname{char}(K) )$

Proof of "$\Rightarrow$": Assume $n \ge \operatorname{char}(K) =: p$. Consider the matrix whose first $p$ diagonal entries are $1$, all other entries $0$.

Proof of "$\Leftarrow$": See e.g. the answer to [Trace Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3803758/96384). Notice for the case of positive characteristic $p$ that under our assumption, $\operatorname{tr}(Id_{m\times m}) = m \neq 0 \in K$ for all $1 \le m \le n < p$, which makes the argument in that answer go through.

(It would be interesting to see which of the proofs in [Traces of all positive powers of a matrix are zero implies it is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/159167/96384), [$\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A^{2})= \ldots = \operatorname{tr}(A^{n})=0$ implies $A$ is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1229233/96384), [The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^n$ if and only if $\text{Tr}(A^i)=0$ for all $1\le i \le n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983730/96384) also go through assuming $n < p$.)

---

So of course

$$(\forall n: P(n)) \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{char}(K)=0$$