# Proving nilpotency of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $k\times k$ matrices such that $AB^k - B^kA = B$. I have to prove that $B$ is nilpotent. It is easy to see that $\text{trace}(B) = 0$. I do not have any idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Well you could try to prove that $\text{trace}(B^2)=0$ as well, etc

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/traces-of-all-positive-powers-of-a-matrix-are-zero-implies-it-is-nilpotent?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using properties of the trace and the characterization of $B$, you can show that:
$$trace(B^n)=0 \quad \forall n>0$$
which implies that $B$ is nilpotent as shown here:
[Traces of all positive powers of a matrix are zero implies it is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/traces-of-all-positive-powers-of-a-matrix-are-zero-implies-it-is-nilpotent)

Comment: Edited, thank you for the suggestion