# Proof of Nilpotency of Matrix All Whose Powers Have Vanishing Trace Without Using Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, extension-field, alternative-proof, trace, nilpotence

Let $k$ be a field and let $A\in M^{n\times n}(k)$ be such that $tr(A^m)=0$ for all $m\in \mathbb N$ (or all $m\leq n$). Prove that $A$ is nilpotent.

The canonical proof can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/159201/223002). However, this answer uses the existence of a splitting field of the characteristic polynomial. I wonder if there are any more elementary proofs.

Comment: Perhaps you would prefer the second proof given in that same link; arguably, using Newton's identities is still "elementary".

Comment: Note that this result in general fails to hold in the case that $k$ is of finite characteristic. For instance, all powers of
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
have trace zero when $k$ has characteristic $2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann This solution still assume the existence of $n$ generalized eigenvalues, which I disallow.

Comment: you really don't need a splitting field of an arbitrary char poly over $\mathbb K$.  One sufficient approach: prove Newton's Identities as a trace identity over $\mathbb C$.  Then consider the polynomial ring $R:=\mathbb Z[\mathbf x]$ and $A' \in R^{n\times n}$ -- trace form of Newton's Identities holds here (why?) and then do a substitution homomorphism into your field $\mathbb K$.  This last step requires care when you have positive characteristic-- as evidenced by the fact that your opening two sentences are still innacurate.  No field theory required -- just ring theory and FTA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will consider only the case where $k$ has characteristic $0$.

One approach is as follows. As [is noted here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties), the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ can be expressed in terms of the trace of the powers of $A$, with
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(\textstyle\bigwedge^m A\right) = \frac{1}{m!}  
\begin{vmatrix}  \operatorname{tr}A  &   m-1 &0&\cdots & \\
\operatorname{tr}A^m  &\operatorname{tr}A&  m-2 &\cdots & \\
 \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots    \\
\operatorname{tr}A^{m-1} &\operatorname{tr}A^{m-2}& & \cdots & 1    \\ 
\operatorname{tr}A^m  &\operatorname{tr}A^{m-1}& & \cdots & \operatorname{tr}A
\end{vmatrix},
$$
where $(-1)^m \operatorname{tr}\left(\textstyle\bigwedge^m A\right)$ is the coefficient of $t^{n-m}$ in the characteristic polynomial $p(t)$ of $A$.  If all powers of $A$ have trace zero, then it follow via the above that the non-leading coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are zero, which is to say that $p(t) = t^n$.

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, it follows that $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: How totally arcane!

Comment: @TedShifrin I can't tell if you mean that as a compliment or an insult but I absolutely agree

Comment: No insult to you, but in my 50 years of knowing, using, and teaching linear algebra I’ve never encountered such a thing. I did upvote your answer. I don’t like the OP’s limitations :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for that :). I agree that OP's limitations are bizarre at best; an arcane answer for an arcane question I suppose