# Are the eigenvalues of the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ identical?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

***Are the eigenvalues of the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ identical? If yes, why?***

From the examples that I have tried I think they are identical but I just can't come up with a formal proof for this.

Comment: You can find more reasons [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821934/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-matrices).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ that is $\exists x\neq 0$ and

$$
AB(x)=\lambda x 
$$
$BAB(x)=BA(Bx)=\lambda (Bx)$

Then $Bx$ is eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Only case which we have to worry about is when $Bx=0$. For that case see that $\lambda x =0$ which contradicts the very starting assumption (except when $\lambda =0$).