# If M and N are square matrices, Prove that MN and NM have the same eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Title says it all. I was thinking of using the fact that the determinant and the trace are thesame , but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: Assuming that $M$ is invertible, $M^{-1}(MN)M = NM$. Two conjugated matrices always have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Actually, this has been asked so many times (with enlightening different answers): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-ab-and-ba-have-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173614/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-qquad?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821934/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-matrices?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050372/is-it-true-that-sigmaab-sigmaba?lq=1 among them.